# How can I make an image fit a particular aspect ratio, and scale with device/browser width? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, image, xenforo

I'm new to complex coding (most of my experience is with HTML, so I'm clunky at best with CSS and JS), and am running into a terribly irksome issue with a Star Wars forum I manage.

Our forum is through XenForo, and we would like the capability to upload banner images for separate forum pages that scale with browser/device width, and fit neatly into a defined aspect ratio (4:1 or 5:1 would be ideal). Problem is, I don't know how to do this. I've tried Googling a variety of solutions and nothing has worked.

I could really use some help from someone who knows what the hell they're looking at. I don't know what's important and what's not. `.nodesbackgrounds` is the tag in question. Here is a link to a live page with a forum banner uploaded: https://forums.sithempire.net/index.php?forums/house-vahl.16/

Here is the code for the template where the banner image is defined:

```
<style>
    .nodesbackgrounds {background:url({$forum.Node.catfor}) !important; height:250px; width:100%; margin-bottom:20px;}
</style>
</xf:if>

<div class="nodesbackgrounds"></div>

<xf:title page="{$page}">{$forum.Node.title}</xf:title>
<xf:description>{$forum.Node.description|raw}</xf:description>

<xf:css src="structured_list.less" />

<xf:macro template="metadata_macros" name="canonical_url"
    arg-canonicalUrl="{{ link('canonical:forums', $forum, $canonicalFilters + {'page': $page}) }}" />

<xf:head option="rss_forum"><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{{ phrase('rss_feed_for_x', {'title': $forum.title})|for_attr }}" href="{{ link('forums/index.rss', $forum) }}" /></xf:head>

<xf:macro template="forum_macros" name="forum_page_options" arg-forum="{$forum}" />
<xf:breadcrumb source="$forum.getBreadcrumbs(false)" />

<xf:pageaction if="$forum.canCreateThread()">
    <xf:button href="{{ link('forums/post-thread', $forum) }}" class="button--cta" icon="write">
        {{ phrase('post_thread') }}
    </xf:button>
</xf:pageaction>

<xf:if is="$pendingApproval">
    <div class="blockMessage blockMessage--important">{{ phrase('content_submitted_displayed_pending_approval') }}</div>
</xf:if>

<xf:if is="$nodeTree">
    <xf:ad position="forum_view_above_node_list" arg-forum="{$forum}" />
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-container">
            <div class="block-body">
                <xf:macro template="forum_list" name="node_list"
                    arg-children="{$nodeTree}"
                    arg-extras="{$nodeExtras}"
                    arg-depth="2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <xf:ad position="forum_view_below_node_list" arg-forum="{$forum}" />
</xf:if>

<xf:if is="$canInlineMod">
    <xf:js src="xf/inline_mod.js" min="1" />
</xf:if>

<xf:ad position="forum_view_above_thread_list" arg-forum="{$forum}" />
<div class="block" data-xf-init="{{ $canInlineMod ? 'inline-mod' : '' }}" data-type="thread" data-href="{{ link('inline-mod') }}">

    <div class="block-outer"><xf:trim>
        <xf:pagenav page="{$page}" perpage="{$perPage}" total="{$total}"
            link="forums" data="{$forum}" params="{$filters}"
            wrapperclass="block-outer-main" />
        <xf:if contentcheck="true">
            <div class="block-outer-opposite">
                <div class="buttonGroup">
                <xf:contentcheck>
                    <xf:if is="$canInlineMod">
                        <xf:macro template="inline_mod_macros" name="button" />
                    </xf:if>
                    <xf:if is="$xf.visitor.user_id">
                        <xf:button href="{{ link('forums/mark-read', $forum, {'date': $xf.time}) }}"
                            class="button--link" overlay="true">
                            {{ phrase('mark_read') }}
                        </xf:button>
                    </xf:if>
                    <xf:if is="$forum.canWatch()">
                        <xf:button href="{{ link('forums/watch', $forum) }}" class="button--link"
                            data-xf-click="switch-overlay"
                            data-sk-watch="{{ phrase('watch') }}"
                            data-sk-unwatch="{{ phrase('unwatch') }}">
                            <xf:if is="{$forum.Watch.{$xf.visitor.user_id}}">{{ phrase('unwatch') }}<xf:else />{{ phrase('watch') }}</xf:if>
                        </xf:button>
                    </xf:if>
                </xf:contentcheck>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xf:if>
    </xf:trim></div>

    <xf:set var="$dateLimits" value="{{ {
        '-1': phrase('any_time'),
        '7': phrase('x_days', {'days': '7'}),
        '14': phrase('x_days', {'days': '14'}),
        '30': phrase('x_days', {'days': '30'}),
        '60': phrase('x_months', {'months': '2'}),
        '90': phrase('x_months', {'months': '3'}),
        '182': phrase('x_months', {'months': '6'}),
        '365': phrase('1_year')
    } }}" />
    <xf:set var="$sortOrders" value="{{ {
        'last_post_date': phrase('last_message'),
        'post_date': phrase('first_message'),
        'title': phrase('title'),
        'reply_count': phrase('replies'),
        'view_count': phrase('views'),
        'first_post_reaction_score': phrase('first_message_reaction_score')
    } }}" />

    <div class="block-container">
        <div class="block-filterBar">
            <div class="filterBar">
                <xf:if contentcheck="true">
                    <ul class="filterBar-filters">
                    <xf:contentcheck>
                        <xf:if is="$filters.prefix_id">
                            <li><a href="{{ link('forums', $forum, $filters|replace('prefix_id', null)) }}"
                                class="filterBar-filterToggle" data-xf-init="tooltip" title="{{ phrase('remove_this_filter')|for_attr }}">
                                <span class="filterBar-filterToggle-label">{{ phrase('prefix:') }}</span>
                                {{ prefix_title('thread', $filters.prefix_id) }}</a></li>
                        </xf:if>
                        <xf:if is="$filters.starter_id AND $starterFilter">
                            <li><a href="{{ link('forums', $forum, $filters|replace('starter_id', null)) }}"
                                class="filterBar-filterToggle" data-xf-init="tooltip" title="{{ phrase('remove_this_filter')|for_attr }}">
                                <span class="filterBar-filterToggle-label">{{ phrase('started_by:') }}</span>
                                {$starterFilter.username}</a></li>
                        </xf:if>
                        <xf:if is="$filters.last_days AND {$dateLimits.{$filters.last_days}}">
                            <li><a href="{{ link('forums', $forum, $filters|replace('last_days', null)) }}"
                                class="filterBar-filterToggle" data-xf-init="tooltip" title="{{ phrase('remove_this_filter')|for_attr }}">
                                <span class="filterBar-filterToggle-label">{{ phrase('last_updated:') }}</span>
                                {$dateLimits.{$filters.last_days}}</a></li>
                        </xf:if>
                        <xf:if is="$filters.order AND {$sortOrders.{$filters.order}}">
                            <li><a href="{{ link('forums', $forum, $filters|replace({'order': null, 'direction': null})) }}"
                                class="filterBar-filterToggle" data-xf-init="tooltip" title="{{ phrase('return_to_default_order')|for_attr }}">
                                <span class="filterBar-filterToggle-label">{{ phrase('sort_by:') }}</span>
                                {$sortOrders.{$filters.order}}
                                <xf:fa icon="{{ $filters.direction == 'asc' ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down' }}" />
                                <span class="u-srOnly"><xf:if is="$filters.direction == 'asc'">{{ phrase('ascending') }}<xf:else />{{ phrase('descending') }}</xf:if></span>
                            </a></li>
                        </xf:if>
                    </xf:contentcheck>
                    </ul>
                </xf:if>

                <a class="filterBar-menuTrigger" data-xf-click="menu" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">{{ phrase('filters') }}</a>
                <div class="menu menu--wide" data-menu="menu" aria-hidden="true"
                    data-href="{{ link('forums/filters', $forum, $filters) }}"
                    data-load-target=".js-filterMenuBody">
                    <div class="menu-content">
                        <h4 class="menu-header">{{ phrase('show_only:') }}</h4>
                        <div class="js-filterMenuBody">
                            <div class="menu-row">{{ phrase('loading...') }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <xf:set var="$qtPos">{{ ($sortInfo.order == 'last_post_date' && $sortInfo.direction == 'asc') ? 'bottom' : 'top' }}</xf:set>

        <div class="block-body">
            <div class="structItemContainer">
                <xf:macro template="thread_list_macros" name="quick_thread"
                    arg-forum="{$forum}"
                    arg-page="{$page}"
                    arg-order="{$sortInfo.order}"
                    arg-direction="{$sortInfo.direction}" />
                <xf:if is="$stickyThreads is not empty OR $threads is not empty">
                    <xf:if is="$stickyThreads is not empty">
                        <div class="structItemContainer-group structItemContainer-group--sticky">
                            <xf:foreach loop="$stickyThreads" value="$thread">
                                <xf:macro template="thread_list_macros" name="item" arg-thread="{$thread}" arg-forum="{$forum}" />
                            </xf:foreach>
                        </div>

                        <xf:ad position="forum_view_below_stickies" arg-forum="{$forum}" />
                    </xf:if>

                    <div class="structItemContainer-group js-threadList">
                        <xf:if is="$threads is not empty">
                            <xf:foreach loop="$threads" value="$thread">
                                <xf:macro template="thread_list_macros" name="item" arg-thread="{$thread}" arg-forum="{$forum}" />
                            </xf:foreach>
                            <xf:if is="$showDateLimitDisabler">
                                <div class="structItem structItem--note">
                                    <div class="structItem-cell">
                                        <a href="{{ link('forums', $forum, {'page': $page, 'no_date_limit': 1} + $filters) }}">
                                            {{ phrase('show_older_items') }}
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </xf:if>
                        </xf:if>
                    </div>
                <xf:elseif is="$filters" />
                    <div class="structItemContainer-group js-threadList">
                        <div class="structItem js-emptyThreadList">
                            <div class="structItem-cell">{{ phrase('there_no_threads_matching_your_filters') }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <xf:else />
                    <div class="structItemContainer-group js-threadList">
                        <div class="structItem js-emptyThreadList">
                            <div class="structItem-cell">{{ phrase('there_no_threads_in_this_forum') }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </xf:if>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block-outer block-outer--after">
        <xf:pagenav
            page="{$page}" perpage="{$perPage}" total="{$total}"
            link="forums" data="{$forum}" params="{$filters}"
            wrapperclass="block-outer-main" />
        <xf:showignored wrapperclass="block-outer-opposite" />
        <xf:if is="!$forum.canCreateThread()">
            <div class="block-outer-opposite">
                <xf:if is="$xf.visitor.user_id">
                    <span class="button is-disabled">
                        {{ phrase('no_permission_to_post') }}
                        <!-- this is not interactive so shouldn't be a button element -->
                    </span>
                <xf:else />
                    <xf:button href="{{ link('login') }}" class="button--link" overlay="true">
                        {{ phrase('log_in_or_register_to_post') }}
                    </xf:button>
                </xf:if>
            </div>
        </xf:if>
    </div>
</div>
<xf:ad position="forum_view_below_thread_list" arg-forum="{$forum}" />

<xf:widgetpos id="forum_view_sidebar" context-forum="{$forum}" position="sidebar" />
```

I know this is a lot to ask for, but I am at a complete loss. I don't know anyone personally I can ask for help, so if there's anyone here who's willing to help, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Hi, good question. However, I still don't understand some parts. It would be nice if you could **explicitly** mention an example of what you want to achieve. Is this what you want to achieve? 1. Someone uploads a picture of 500x1000 (aspect ratio 1:2); 2. You place that picture to a container div that somehow always maintains an aspect ratio of 4:1; 3. Upon placing said picture, some parts will be cropped, but the center part of the cropped image is centered inside the container. Is this what you want to achieve? If not, please elaborate and provide pictures (to make the question clearer).

Comment: Furthermore, the code you provided will not help anyone (so many parts seem irrelevant). I recommend identifying the important parts and create a minimal reproducible example as per the guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example